# "failed to open required file" error, yet the file is there

Tags: php, include

I am getting these errors:

> PHP Fatal error:  main() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/usr/share/pear/Mail.php' (include_path='.:/var/www/vhosts/xxx.net/httpdocs/protected/modules/rbam/models:/var/www/vhosts/xxx.net/httpdocs/protected/extensions/translations/components:/var/www/vhosts/xxx.net/httpdocs/protected/extensions/runactions/components:/var/www/vhosts/xxx.net/httpdocs/protected/components:/var/www/vhosts/xxx.net/httpdocs/protected/models:/usr/share/pear:') in /var/www/vhosts/xxx.net/httpdocs/protected/components/MailComponent.php on line 70

First of all, the include statement is not in line 70 of my `MailComponent.php`, it is on line 3 (but `MailComponent.php` has exactly 69 lines so that may just be a bug in the way PHP reports the error)

```
require_once '/usr/share/pear/Mail.php';
```

The file `/usr/share/pear/Mail.php` is right there, at `/usr/share/pear/Mail.php`, it belongs to root but it has read permissions to everybody; and as you can see `/usr/share/pear` IS in the include path. And furthermore, this used to work until recently and I haven't touched it.

So what may be the issue?!?!?

**EDIT**: I think it's something related to the fact that the folder where the included file is is outside the `httpdocs folder`, but why so and how do I allow it?

(I'm also puzzled at that `main()`, I don't have any such method anywhere; I'm using Yii which does have a couple of `main()` methods here and there (just grepped) though the error is reported to be in my code, allegedly in my `MailComponent.php` where the include_once is).

```
<?php

require_once '/usr/share/pear/Mail.php'; // PEAR Mail
require_once '/usr/share/pear/Mail/mime.php'; // PEAR Mail_mime

class MailComponent extends CApplicationComponent {

    public $defaultHeaders=array();
    public $debugUsers=false;
    public $debugAdmins=false;
    public $debugEmail='matteosistisette@gmail.com';
    public $backend='mail';

    public function sendMail($address, $subject, $body, $headers=array(), $isadmin=false) {

        $actualheaders=array_merge($this->defaultHeaders, $headers);
        $actualheaders['Subject']=$subject;

        $mail = new Mail_mime(array(
            "text_charset" => "utf-8",
            "html_charset" => "utf-8",
            "eol" => "\n"
        ));

        $mail->setTxtBody($body);

        if (($isadmin && $this->debugAdmins) || (!$isadmin && $this->debugUsers)) {
            $address=str_replace('@','_AT_',$address)." <".$this->debugEmail.">";
            //$address=$this->debugEmail;
        }
        $actualheaders['To']=$address;
        $headersencoded=array();
        foreach ($actualheaders as $header=>$value) {
            $headersencoded[$header]=$mail->encodeHeader($header, $value, "utf-8", "quoted-printable");
        }
        //$to=$mail->encodeHeader('To',$address,"utf-8", "quoted-printable");
        $to=$headersencoded['To'];
        $msg=@$mail->get();
        $actualheaders=$mail->headers($headersencoded);
        @$factory=& Mail::factory($this->backend);
        @$ret=$factory->send($to,$actualheaders,$msg);
        if ($ret instanceof PEAR_Error) Yii::log('ERROR SENDING MAIL TO '.$to, 'error');
        return $ret;     
    }

    public function notifyAdmins($role, $area, $subjectcode, $bodycode, $params=array()) {
        $admins=Yii::app()->authManager->getUsers($role);
        $users=array();
        foreach ($admins as $userid) {
            $user=User::model()->findByPk($userid);
            if ($user===null) continue;
            if ($user->current_area_id!=$area->id) continue;
            if ($user->email===null || ($email=trim($user->email))=='') continue;
            $lang=$user->preferredLanguage;
            $params['{CHANNEL_NAME}']=I::tattr($area->partialRoot, 'menu.home', $lang);
            $params['{USER}']=$user->getActualDisplayName();
            $subject=I::t($subjectcode,$lang,$params);
            $body=I::t($bodycode,$lang,$params);
            $this->sendMail($email, $subject, $body, array(), true);
        }
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: We need the code of MailComponent.php

Comment: The `main()` function is the function of the PHP interpreter itself. It is having problems even parsing or executing your code.

Comment: PHP was developed by some guys who really knew what they were doing. I suspect their error messages can be bogus? Its us who have to understand things better.

Comment: @Broncha I think if it was a parse problem I would get a different error wouldn't I

Comment: @HankyPankyㇱ: "PHP was developed by some guys who really knew what they were doing"????????????? Is it possible that you are on hard drugs?

Comment: @HankyPankyㇱ that's what I'm trying to do: understand things. I've edited the title, I guess it's more correct now. Even software developed by guys who really know what they are doing is usually not bug-free. The error message is at the very least incomplete (should indicate why the file can't be opened e.g."no such file or directory" or "permission denied" or "violation of whatever security policy"....) AND inconsistent ("line 70" of a file that has 69 lines, and indicating a failure of a require which is at line 3). Anyway I just want to know why a require can fail to open a file that exists

Comment: Check your file permissions.

Comment: What I can say is the line number it is referencing is not bogus, as I have also been through such error. Mostly happens to me when the code block (class, function) is not well formatted. Sometimes throws error on the `Lastline +1`  of the file. And mostly error lies in codes before or after the included file.

Comment: @Broncha, that's not the case here.
I have copied all PEAR to a folder withiin httpdocs/protected/vendors, added a Yii::import() at the beginning and then modified the  require_once() to point to the new location and everything works now (without changing any other line of code. So it's definetly NOT an issue with malformed code. Of course I'm not happy with the workaround (copying pear!!!) so I'm still looking for a real solution. I too have often incurred in malformed code and the error in lastline+1 but in those cases the error is "unexpected end of file" or other parse-related stuff.

Comment: @Ondřej Mirtes I had already checked previous to asking as I already noted in the question. File permissions are 644

Comment: I think it's something related to the fact that the folder where the included file is is outside the httpdocs folder, but why so and how do I allow it?

Comment: Might be open_basedir problem?

Comment: @OndřejMirtes interesting, that could be it. Are you sure open_basedir affects include, though? From the documentation it's not clear (damn). I suspect open_basedir only affects functions that read files, such as fopen and the like; not sure though. Do you know for sure?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the correct version of the file "MailComponent.php" is being loaded? If, as you say, this file has 69 lines, and the error appears on line 70, I'd start by suspecting the error is referring to some other MailComponent.php file.

Comment: It is the one being loaded. I edited it with a workaround that worked, so it took effect.
I think the lastline+1 is just because something is wrong in the way php does the parsing and error handling (combined) - the same as when invalid code causes a parse error at the end of the file, though in this case there is no syntax error and hence the error, whatever it is, could and should be reported properly

Comment: maybe it's related to the autoloader or something (i.e. the actual loading of the required files is deferred to after parsing all the file, because they are not loaded if not used, or something like that). I don't have a thorough understanding of how the autoloader works.